# Remove Navigation Bar Shadow/Line in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to Remove Navigation Bar Shadow and Line of content page in Xamarin.forms.
Is it possible to do this without rendering.

Answer (score 5):

For just Xamarin Forms, iOS. Add this to your AppDelegate

```
 UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage(); //No line under the navigation
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this render class inside you xamarin ios project

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer))]
namespace YOUR_IOS_NAMESPACE
{
    public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage(); 
        }
    }
}
```